# video load function in typescript throws error

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to load a video dynamically. TypeScript throws this error because it thinks I'm doing it on a HTML element (which is what is returned via the jquery selector), but everything works as expected. I can change out videos without any issues (besides this error).

Code:

```
let url = 'https://myurl.com/videos/';
url = url + event + '.mp4';
$('#video-player video source').attr('src', url);
$('#video-player video').load();
```

`ERROR in src/app/secure/events/events.component.ts(43,5): error TS2554: Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0.`

I also tried casting it to  but it throws another error saying `Types of property 'height' are incompatible.`.

How do I get rid of the error?

UPDATE:
Ended up just setting the src attribute (using Angular) on the video element and setting autoplay. It all works now and no errors:

```
<video width="800" [src]="videoSource" controls autoplay>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: Could you post your code please? This makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Updated code section. This code works and loads the correct video. It just doesn't compile in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The *[jQuery Api Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/)* should help you:

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )

The `.load()` function needs at least an **Url** to work.